# extract subelement subset in one regex

Tags: regex, splunk

I have an xml with multiple element 2 (can be 0 or more...)

How could I extract out of

```
<xml><element1></element1><element2></element2><element2></element2><element3></element3>
```

OR

```
<xml><element1></element1><element3></element3>
```

to get 
element1,element2,element2,element3
OR
element1,element3

I tried

```
(?P<element1>.*?)(?P<element2><element2>.*(?!</element2>)*)(?P<element3>.*)
```

does not work in both situations...

Its for Splunk, so I can only do regex, not code...

Comment: I can't, it is for Splunk, and I have good reason to make it in regex...

Answer (score 0):

You want a regex replace:

**Find:**  `(.*?)(<([^>]+?)\/?>.*?(?:<\/\s*\3\s*>)?)`

**Replace:** `$3,`

#### Demo

http://regex101.com/r/xA8uK4

Comment: Thank you, I didn't knew the website ist really cool...
But the element is not element\d in reality, they have specific names... so it doesn't work like this...

Comment: @schmirrwurst I have updated my answer for allowing any element. Self closing elements are also allowed.